# PNPM not overriding package

Tags: javascript, package, overriding, pnpm

I have the following config in my `package.json`:

```
 "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "loader-utils@1.4.0": "^1.4.1"
    }
  }
```

I then run `pnpm install`.

In my `pnpm.lock`:

```
lockfileVersion: 5.4

overrides:
  loader-utils@1.4.0: ^1.4.1
```

However further down I can see that `loader-utils` has not been updated:

```
  /babel-loader/8.2.3_te6ollfzjcco6mbxjl755ucqke:
    resolution: {integrity: sha512-n4Zeta8NC3QAsuyiizu0GkmRcQ6clkV9WFUnUf1iXP//IeSKbWjofW3UHyZVwlOB4y039YQKefawyTn64Zwbuw==}
    engines: {node: '>= 8.9'}
    peerDependencies:
      '@babel/core': ^7.0.0
      webpack: '>=2'
    dependencies:
      ...
      loader-utils: 1.4.0
```

If I run `pnpm why loader-utils` I see:

```
└─┬ gatsby-plugin-sharp 4.25.0 peer
  └─┬ gatsby 4.25.4 peer
    ├─┬ @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin 0.5.10
    │ └── loader-utils 2.0.4
    ├─┬ babel-loader 8.2.3
    │ └── loader-utils 1.4.0
```

**Why is the version of `loader-utils` not being overridden?**

Comment: Can you add your entire package.json? (or even better a link to the repo). This way I can see a reproduction and try to fix it.